# GCC : and/or keywords

Tags: gcc, keyword

It seems these keywords work in GCC, and not part of a C++ standard.

Could you tell, why it's part of GCC and where is it documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, they *are* part of standards. In C, they're macros introduced by *iso646.h*. In C++, they're bona fide keywords. Check sections 2.5 and 2.11 of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4):

ANSI C provides these as standard; see iso646.h

They are part of ISO C++ and do not require a specific header in C++

The GCC option to disable them, -fno-operator-names, is documented in the C++ dialect options section of the GCC user manual.